# Setting ManyToManyField intermediate field in form in Django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have such model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through="Membership")


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am working on a View, in which user could assign Persons to a Group. I want to store User who created the relation (Membership). Something like that:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ["members"]
        widgets = {"members": forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}


class GroupView(UpdateView):
    form_class = GroupForm
    model = Group

    def form_valid(self, form):
        for member in form.cleaned_data["members"]:
            member.user = self.request.user
            member.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

However, I'm getting error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_membership.created_by_id

Of course, I could make `created_by` field nullable and set `created_by` later, but what is the correct way to solve this?